# RASPBMC Web Server Control Via Kodi iOS App

Tags: pi-2, raspbmc, kodi, ios

I am using the Kodi app to control the media centre perfectly fine. However when the Raspberry Pi reboots it will no longer connect.

A fix for this is to toggle the setting in RASPBMC to allow control via HTTP off and then back on (this is still on after reboot), however this requires me to pull my usb keyboard out every time the Pi is shut down/ performs updates.

Does anyone know of a fix for this issue?

Comment: Does your Pi have a static IP address?

Comment: No it is not however it is using the same IP address (checked on router).

Comment: You first step needs to be giving the Pi a static IP address. This is so every time you turn the Pi on it gets given the same IP address, this makes accessing it from the app easier.

Answer (score 0):

Tasks that need to be done automatically at boot are best handled through either a [startup script](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=122215) or a [cron task](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/cron.md).